# CSS - images not displaying

Tags: html, css, image

having trouble with a CSS problem, but I can't figure it out.  none of my images are displaying, yet they have working urls and the HTML is correct.

there's no image styling, and the image class's only styling is: `.postimg { width: 100%; }`

problem here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4pmUu/5/

this probably has a really simple solution, but i can't figure out what's wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the correct image tag. To show an image in HTML use the `<img>` tag.

see http://jsfiddle.net/4pmUu/7/

Comment: argh!!  so obvious!  this HTML was generated from jade.  i thought 'i' was synonymous with 'img' in jade syntax.  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you just have the image tag wrong.  `<i>` is italic text; you want `<img>` instead.  That is, `<img src="http://ruby.colorado.edu/~smyth/Research/Images/Volcanix/MtFuji02.jpg" class="postimg" />`

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute `<i ...></i>` and use it (below) it should work.

```
<img src="http://ruby.colorado.edu/~smyth/Research/Images/Volcanix/MtFuji02.jpg" class="postimg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the image tag as:

`<i src="http://ruby.colorado.edu/~smyth/Research/Images/Volcanix/MtFuji02.jpg" class="postimg">` this is where the actual error it.

The correct way to do is to write `<img...` use this:

`<img src="http://ruby.colorado.edu/~smyth/Research/Images/Volcanix/MtFuji02.jpg" class="postimg" alt="photo" />`

Also please note that, using `alt=""` is necessary in images, as if the image is not loaded because of some issue, the user will be shown a text about that image.